# Installing phpw55-mcrypt on RedHat enterprise 5

Tags: redhat, mcrypt

Thank you in advance for reading this question,

I am trying to run a Laravel web application on an old RedHat server that is provided by my company. I am getting the error that MCRYPT is not active (it is not installed). When trying to run a yum install php55w-mcrypt yum gives the error

```
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
php55w-mcrypt-5.5.26-1.w5.x86_64 from webtatic-el5 has depsolv
  --> Missing Dependency: libltdl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by p
pt-5.5.26-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic-el5)
Error: Missing Dependency: libltdl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by
ypt-5.5.26-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic-el5)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

I have tried installing the dependency, but I can not seem to find the libltdl.so.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround / does anyone know where to find the library?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the required libtools here:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libtool
wget < correct file type for your server >
yum install lib*
rm lib*

Then searched on the same webpage for libltdl.so.3()
wget < correct file type for your server >
yum install lib*

After installing the dependencies the yum install php55w-mcrypt could be installed and laravel worked like a charm!